# Joomla CMS and Spring Framework

Tags: spring, architecture, joomla

I want to create a Web application by combining Joomla CMS with Spring Framework. What would be the best way to build/use a single sign-on for both?. All the pages on the website will be serviced by Joomla CMS, but those that require authentication/authorization will be done with Spring Framework. The later will retrieve widgets from Joomla CMS to ensure the same User Interface.
I would appreciate any suggestion or pointer to information about this topic
Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overload Joomla **User plug-in**, save/edit/delete/login/etc. This will hep you understand user event that you will need to implement, http://docs.joomla.org/Reference:User_Events_for_Plugin_System. Also look at the following file `plugins/user/example.php`

In my opinion, mixing 2 different languages PHP and Java in 1 project is a little extreme. I would keep the projects separate and created my own Joomla/Spring Field API. Then would make API call in Joomla components/modules/plug-ins to integrate with Spring Framework.

Another thing, do not modify Joomla's native code to achieve what you want (I mean don't rewrite base classes that Joomla uses). Instead create your own library in the `/libraries/` directory and extend the classes. If you decide to adopt API, you might want to have some API object in your model. Create your own base model `/libraries/your_lib/application/component/` then when you are creating a model in the component change the import code to `jimport('your_lib.application.component.model')`

Answer (score 0):

[IOPLEX](http://www.ioplex.com/) sell a Java library (Jespa) to provide single signon using Windows NTLM credentials, they also have a Joomla plugin.  Could be appropriate if you're authenticating against ActiveDirectory and have Windows clients.

Comment: My deployment is on Linux. No LDAP involved

Answer (score 0):

i think using web service will give the chance to not touch the basic code of joomla because joomla give you hand to make an xmlrpc  , and you have to keep in mind the session controle the best think is to let joomla manage session and creating a user plugin to make a specifique action in the login and logout event. hope will help.